# C# работа с базой

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle

Ребят, рассчитываю на ваш опыт!

Дилема стоит - работу с базой в C# производить через прямые запросы или вызывать хранимые процедуры, в теле которых будут эти прямые запросы.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что будет быстрее работать, правильнее, грамотнее, коректнее?

P.s.: не напоминайте про entity framework. В проекте он не прижился, поэтому в репозитории раскиданы прямые запросы.

Comment: вы определитесь, вам надо быстрее, правильнее, грамотнее или корректнее? А вообще, если у вас нет причин использовать хранимки, то лучше их не использовать

Comment: Если хотя бы два требования будут выполняться, то будет уже хорошо.

Comment: например, правильно выделять слой доступа к данным в отдельную абстракцию. Корректно ли это в вашем случае? Только вы это можете знать

Comment: Это уже сделано. Вопрос не в этом.

Comment: ну или грамотно использовать dapper, если уж хочется писать SQL руками. Быстро ли это? Имхо, индексированные представления скорее всего быстрее. Нужна ли вам такая скорость? Только вам это знать

Comment: Вот про dapper не слышал. Спасибо!) почитаю!)

Comment: что касается хранимок, то как только вы напишете первую хранимку, сразу возникнет соблазн запилить в неё какую то логику. Один раз так сделаете, другой, третий, и вот вы снова в 2003 году и ваша логика приложения размазана между кодом и базой и никто не понимает, что происходит, когда юзер добавляет товар в корзину

Comment: с хранимками важно правильное версионирование и удобный деплой организовать, и да, для примитивных операций лучше не использовать

Comment: Ммм.. От души за последние два сообщения!

Comment: Чем слабее ваша типизация (голый sql или его же хранимки), тем больше боли в развитии и поддержке. Хотя бы dapper, как выше советуют. Если проект серьезный и надолго - то лучше что-то типа EF или nHibernate.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)